# Variable going back to 0 when label saved

Tags: ios, swift, label, uilabel, nsuserdefaults

I made an app where I save a label that I can make it go up or down one number in my app. But if I lose out of my app and open it back up, if i make the label go up again than it resets back to zero and goes to one. This is because I have to set the variable value to zero. Here is my code:

```
    @IBOutlet var goal: UILabel!

    @IBAction func player1button(sender: AnyObject)
    {
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setValue(goal.text!, forKey:"firstGoal")
    }

    var goal1 = 0

    @IBAction func goalUp(sender: AnyObject)
    {
    goal1++
    goal.text = "\(goal1)"
    }

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    goal.text = (NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("firstGoal") as? String)
    }
```

Im saving the goal number then calling it back later in the text. Please show me a way to fix it so it just adds on to the previous number.

Answer (score 0):

in viewDidLoad() add

```
goal1 = Int((NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("firstGoal") as? String)!)
```

this will set the int variable you are using to keep track of the goals to the correct value when the app loads. currently you are only setting the text label to the correct value.

Comment: thanks! should I still keep the var goal1 = 0 up there?

Comment: yes, you still have to declare the variable.  you can try assigning the NSUserDefaults value instead of 0 but my guess (without trying) is that Xcode may not like this and give an error

Comment: ok and should I do `goal1 = (NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("firstGoal") as? String).toInt()`  or `var goal1 = (NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("firstGoal") as? String).toInt()`

Comment: it would have to be var goal1. this declares the variable. if Xcode gives you an error then go back to assigning the value in viewDidLoad() which is perfectly fine.

Comment: ok but when I use `var goal1 = (NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("firstGoal") as? String).ToInt()` in the view did load it come up with an error saying: value of type string? has no member ToInt.

Comment: Int((NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("firstGoal") as? String)!) does this work?

Comment: no, it didn't work when i put that in the view did load it still reset back to 0. Am i still supposed to have the `var goal1 = 0` above the view did load?

Comment: var goal1 = 0 above viewDidLoad yes. inside viewDidLoad just assign goal1 = ... don't redeclare the variable using var

Answer (score 0):

or you can simply make var `goal1` a global variable , just after the imports and before the class keyword , in case you don't need to keep the data till the next time you open the app itself